# codeception WebDriver irgnores url Parameter

Tags: codeception

I like to use codeception acceptance test to test my PHP Application.

For this I have an `acceptance.suite.yml` configuration, like this:

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver:
            url: "http://myserver"
            window_size: false # disabled in ChromeDriver
            port: 9515
            browser: chrome
            capabilities:
                chromeOptions:
                    args: ["--headless", "--disable-gpu"] # Run Chrome in headless mode
                    prefs:
                        download.default_directory: "/tmp"
        - Yii2:
            part: orm
            entryScript: index-test.php
            cleanup: false
```

When I start the test `codecept run` I get the following error:
 `[ConnectionException] Can't connect to WebDriver at http://127.0.0.1:9515/wd/hub. Make sure that ChromeDriver, GeckoDriver or Selenium Server is running.`

This is strange, because `url` is set to `http://myserver`, which is not localhost.

Question: Why codecept tries to use localhost instead of `http://myserver`?

I also changes the port to make sure, this config-file is really  used. So I found out, that the config-file is used an the `port:`  parameter in the `acceptance.suite.yml` really comes form this file. Only the `url:`  parameter seams not to have an any effect.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Codeception connects to WebDriver daemon, e.g. Chromedriver, and then WebDriver connects to URL.

In your case it fails to connect to WebDriver.
Have you got Chromedriver running on your computer?
If it is running on different machine, you can specify it using `host`parameter.